# Adding own Objective-C framework to Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, bridging-header

I am trying to build my own framework in Objective-C named "NEFramework". There is a class named "Helper" inside that framework. It was inherited from the NSObject. There is a function name "print" inside that class to print out the text.

And then I have created a new Swift project and imported that framework in it.I've tried to create BridgingHeader file to access that framework from my Swift project. Then I added this code in my BridgingHeader file.

```
#import <NEFramework/Helper.h>
```

After adding that line of code, I got this error in that BridgingHeader file.

> 'NEFramework/Helper.h' file not found

Please refer to the following image for more clarification.[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me on this and I am stuck in this place. Thanks.

> Update

I've tried to add `#import <NEFramework/Helper.h>` in the "NEFramework.h" file. That was ok and can build the project with no error. Please refer to the following image for that. [image]

But after adding `#import <NEFramework/NEFramework.h>` and `#import <NEFramework/Helper.h>` in my BridgingHeader file. I got the error again.
[image]

Comment: Did you expose Helper.h publically in the NEFramework.h file? It would be `#import <NEFramework/Helper.h>` in the NEFramework.h file.

Comment: @NimaYousefi I have updated the question as you suggested. But still got the issue. Not sure what am I missing in my BridgingHeader build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling the whole the, I found the reason why I cannot build my header file in "NEFramework.h" file.

I need to go to the Build Phases of my framework and find Headers. And then I moved some header files under the "Project" tab that I need to use in my swift project to under "Public" tab.
Please refer to the image for more clarification. Just sharing for other people like me to build a custom framework. Thanks everyone who answered my questions.
[image]